# Прокси-классы в С++

Tags: proxy, c++

Что такое прокси-классы и для чего они используются?

Comment: http://bit.ly/MuVRhD
Гуглите! один и тот же вопрос на всех форумах!

Comment: Относительно С++ подобных вопросов не так уж и много. А имеющиеся сведения очень скудные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, речь идет о стандартном паттерне проектирования [Прокси](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).